# Using Java's Graphics or Graphics2D classes, how do I paint a String?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paint, graphics2d

I have a `String` and I want to paint it onto an image. I am able to paint points and draw lines, however, even after reading the [Text part of the 2D Graphics tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/text/index.html), I can't figure out how I can take a `String` and paint it onto my drawing.

Unless I'm looking at the wrong tutorial (but it's the one I get whenever I search for anything about Java and painting Strings using `Graphics` or `Graphics2D`), I'm still stumped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the following method.

```
g.drawString();
```

The [`drawString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) method will do what you need.

An example use:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString(5, 40, "Hello World!");
}
```

Just remember, the coordinates are regarding the bottom left of the `String` you are drawing.

Comment: Thanks. Why was there no mention of this in the tutorial that I read? I learned a lot about fonts and stuff, though...

Comment: No idea.  It is a pretty basic thing to do in Swing.

Comment: that's a strange tutorial that seems to contain nothing :D
here 1.4's javadoc for Graphics2D, it's a much better tutorial than the one you were looking at :D
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html

Comment: That wasn't supposed to be a tutorial.  It is just a link to the Javadocs for Graphics, which has `drawString()` in it.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to play with the **shape** of your string (eg: fill:red and stroke:blue):

```
Graphics2D yourGraphicsContext=(...);
Font f= new Font("Dialog",Font.PLAIN,14);
FontRenderContext frc = yourGraphicsContext.getFontRenderContext();
TextLayout tl = new TextLayout(e.getTextContent(), f, frc);
Shape shape= tl.getOutline(null);

//here, you can move your shape with AffineTransform (...)

yourGraphicsContext.setColor(Color.RED);
yourGraphicsContext.fill(shape);
yourGraphicsContext.setColor(Color.BLUE);
yourGraphicsContext.draw(shape);
```